# Should `val` be used when defining class parameters in Scala?

Tags: scala

In the Scala documentation at https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/classes.html, the following example shows a minimal class definition that includes parameters:

```
class Point(var x: Int, var y: Int) {
    ...
}
```

Both of the following code snippets work correctly for me:

- Snippet 1: `class Train(number: Int)`
- Snippet 2: `class Train(val number: Int)`

What would be the benefit of using `val` in snippet 2? From what I understand, by default `val` is implicit. Would code readability by being explicit to say that `number` is a `val` and not a `var` be the only benefit? Thank you.

Comment: In the second snippet `number` is a public member of the class `Train` - In the first snippet `number` is only accessible in the body of the `Train` since it is just an argument of the constructor.

Comment: Thank you @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez. Please write this as an answer.

Comment: From the doc link: "Primary constructor parameters with val and var are public." and about 6 lines down: "Parameters without val or var are private values, visible only within the class."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Snippet 1, `number` is a construction parameter and is not a member of the class. It can only be used inside the constructor (the body of the `class`).

In Snippet 2, `number` is a public read-only member of the class. It can be used by any code that has an instance of the class.

> From what I understand, by default `val` is implicit.

This is not true for `class` parameters but is true for `case class` parameters, which can cause confusion when learning Scala.

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/classes.html) you linked:

> Primary constructor parameters with `val` and `var` are public.

E.g. (as in the example):

```scala
class Point(val x: Int, val y: Int)
val point = new Point(1, 2)
point.x = 3  // <-- does not compile (because vals are immutable)
```

In this definition you can access `x` and `y`, as they are `public val`s

```scala
point.x // 1
point.y // 2
```

The next paragraph explains:

> Parameters without `val` or `var` are private values, visible only within the class.

E.g. (as in the example):

```scala
class Point(x: Int, y: Int)
val point = new Point(1, 2)
point.x  // <-- does not compile
```

In this definition, `x` and `y` are `private val`s

Thus your snippet 1 has a `private val` called `number`
And your snippet 2 has a `public val` called `number`

(Just to note) A small caveat to this is `case class`es, where all arguments of the constructor are public, regardless of the `val` or `var` keyword. If omitted, the variable/value will be public.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in [Lightbend Scala Language - Professional](https://academy.lightbend.com/courses/course-v1:lightbend+LSL-P-Scala-Language-Professional+v1/courseware/c42474c7391143499c111c91dd87a7b0/5831b460cb4948eb85f68343cd90171a/?child=first):

[image]

[image]

I confirmed it from the REPL:

```
scala> class Hello(message: String)
class Hello

scala> val hello = new Hello("Hello, world!")
val hello: Hello = Hello@2a454afb

scala> hello.message
             ^
       error: value message is not a member of Hello

scala> class Hello(val message: String)
class Hello

scala> val hello = new Hello("Hello, world!")
val hello: Hello = Hello@639e35dc

scala> hello.message
val res7: String = Hello, world!
```